# Git. Undo staged changes in working directory, keeping staged area untouched

Tags: git, git-stage

Suppose I have staged a few changes:

```
$ git diff --cached # few changes are stashed

+ change 1 new
  blabla
- change 2 old
+ change 2 new
  blabla
- change 3 old
+ change 3 new
  blabla

$ git diff  # no other changes
```

Now I would like to test my program quickly without change 2. With `git reset head -p; git stash` I can rid of change 2 completely. But I don't want to unstage it, this is just a test, I still want to commit it later on. Therefore **I would like to make the changes opposite to the changes from change 2 in my working directory**. The result should be like this:

```
$ git diff --cached # 1-3 changes are stashed

+ change 1 new
  blabla
- change 2 old
+ change 2 new
  blabla
- change 3 old
+ change 3 new
  blabla

$ git diff  #change 2 is undone

  change 1 new
  blabla
+ change 2 old
- change 2 new
  blabla
  change 3 new
  blabla
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `git stash -p` (which uses the `git add --interactive` machinery) is designed to let you do just this.  I find it more cumbersome than just creating separate commits, though: if you keep the separate commits unpublished, you can easily rearrange, modify, combine, or remove some or all of them later with `git rebase -i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your biggest problems comes from the fact that if your changes are independent(ish), then you should probably commit them independently first and treat them as three different commits. IE, use `git commit --interactive` (or `git add --interactive`) to commit your changes in 3 change commits instead of 1.  That lets you much more easily revert one (like #2) using `git revert`, or other change-management magic to deal with just the commit you're looking for in question.

Comment: Interesting remark, thank you. Can I ask how many commits do you do per day and what is a typical size of commit?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I could give you metrics for myself, because it greatly depends on what I'm working on, etc.  But my policy is small commits are better, but they should be logically grouped together too (ie, pieces that are dependent on each other should be committed together).  Small commits means you can revert pieces more easily.  Or find the commit that broke something more easily.